# Send Post Form Data in Json Format Via Ajax With JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

as the title says I'm sending some post data via ajax. but I keep on getting errors, can anyone take a look at the code and explain why my ajax call keeps failing?

```
submitForm(jQuery('#priceCalc'), {name: 'thingdoto', value: "true"});

function submitForm(form, data) {
        var postData = form.serializeArray(),
            formURL = form.attr("action");

        postData.push(data);
        console.log(postData);
        jQuery.ajax({
                url : formURL,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType : "json",
                data: postData,
                success:function(data)
                {
                        jQuery('#priceTotal').html(data);
                },
                error: function()
                {
                        jQuery('#priceTotal').html('error');
                }
        });
}
```

EDIT: The ajax call returns the error, so it's just not succeeding. Don't know why.

Comment: It'd be, you know, useful to mention what these errors are.

Comment: Oh hey! Sorry it just returns the error, in the ajax call, so I just the string "error". The function does not succeed.

Comment: is the URL hit returning `2xx`?

Comment: Yup, doesn't seem to be an issue with the URL. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Hey, I was declaring two variables in one line you'll notice the comma not semi colon on the line above

Comment: What's the URL? Is it on the same server or cross domain?

Comment: @Steve Hey! Yeah it's on the same server!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a 200 response?  What is in the response body?  Is it actually parseable JSON?

Comment: Chrome network tab gives a 200 OK response, and the consolelog on line 8 looks like just a normal JSON object with 16 entries. So the body should be good?

Comment: Can you share that JSON block? Or at least run it through jsonlint.com to see if it is valid?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the hint @Steve looks like I was passing through an array of objects and not valid JSON at all. So my bad! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 11):

You're sending data as an array, not a JSON string.

You want to do something like this.

```
$("form#ID").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {}
    var Form = this;

    //Gathering the Data
    //and removing undefined keys(buttons)
    $.each(this.elements, function(i, v){
            var input = $(v);
        data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        delete data["undefined"];
    });

    //Form Validation goes here....

    //Save Form Data........
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url : ?,
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        context : Form,
        success : function(callback){
            //Where $(this) => context == FORM
            console.log(JSON.parse(callback));
            $(this).html("Success!");
        },
        error : function(){
            $(this).html("Error!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: This logic "Gathering the Data" works for text fields, but does not work for checkboxes. It always transfers the "value" of the checkbox element regardless whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I just ran into this situation:

[jquery ajax returns success when directly executed, but returns error when attached to button, even though server response is 200 OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993284/jquery-ajax-returns-success-when-directly-executed-but-returns-error-when-attac)

And found out that the problem (in my case) was that calling ajax from a `button` inside a `form` to send JSON seems to cause JQuery to misinterpret the server response -- and always consider it an error. My solution was to change the `form` to a `div` or to change the `button` tag to an `a` tag (using Bootstrap to render a as button)

This worked

```
<div>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

or

```
<form>
    <a></a>
</form>
```