# Handling Huge number of POST parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, post

I am passing close to 1000 parameters to my server. And i got the infamous "More than the maximum number of POST parameters detected" error. I increased the MAX_COUNT value in my local server and it was working fine.

But in my production environment the server admin is not ready to increase the count above 512, he is sighting DOS attacks as the reason.

Is there a best way to pass these 1000+ parameters to the server. I tried compartmentalizing the page into sections and made save buttons available for each section. But if it wasn't possible to compartmentalize, what would be the best practice to send huge number of parameters to a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get around this by posting an XML or JSON document with all of the parameters.  It will require quite a bit changes, but will get you around the restriction without having to deal with the sysadmin.

Comment: could you elaborate...? Are you suggesting that i should get the values from all the input fields and jsonize them and send them as a single parameter.?

Comment: Yes, that is an option.  You would be sending the data as the POST body, not as a parameter.  You could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227789/send-post-form-data-in-json-format-via-ajax-with-jquery) if using JQuery